# Print all files in a directory as text

Tags: windows, notepad++, printing

I want to print all the files in a subdirectory tree as text files (its a bunch of code and config files, all text). I am using Windows 8

The file explorer does not seem to have a "Print" option.

I can open all the files in Notepad++ and then print them, but that will be tedious and also Notepad++ puts these obnoxious headers on the files unless I figure out how to disable that "feature".

Comment: "how to disable that "feature"." Notepad++ > Settings > Preferences > Print and delete what you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this on the command line:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /a-d /b /s "C:\PATH\TO\FOLDER"') do notepad /p %f
```

That will loop through all files in `C:\PATH\TO\FOLDER` and execute `notepad /p`, which prints the file to the default printer.